# I need to define <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> within my jQuery script. How?

Tags: jquery, path

I know that when using Wordpress, in a php file you can say

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/image.png"/>
```

and it knows that you want the current template directory, so that you can make a plugin universal.

I want to add some html dynamically using jQuery that includes something like `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` to define my path.

So my question is, how do get and then define my template path in jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Create a variable in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var templateDirectory = '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>';
</script>
```

From there you can do whatever you want, like so:

```
$('#my-image').attr('src', templateDirectory + '/images/image.png');
```

Comment: This is what I have so far, not to sure how to add the variable to read within some html dynamically added :

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(addPageFlipHTML);

var templateDirectory = '<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>';

function addPageFlipHTML() {

 jQuery('body') // after body tag but inside
   .prepend(
     "<div id='pageflip'><a href=' templateDirectory /plugins/page-flip/images/page_flip.png' alt='' />" //create this html
       + "<span class='msg_block'>Subscribe via RSS</span></a></div>");

}`

Comment: sorry about the bunched up code not sure how to space it out.

Comment: The issue here is you are not properly concatenating (combining) your strings.  I've fixed the offending line (note the `+` signs around the `templateDirectory` variable): `.prepend( "<div id='pageflip'><a href='" + templateDirectory + "/plugins/page-flip/images/page_flip.png' alt='' /> //your code continued...`

Comment: When I look at it in firebug it shows `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` after its been returned to the page. I need to for `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` to return giving the path to my image based on the current template directory. Does that make any sense ?

Comment: Maybe I need to pass a variable that is already defined in php to jQuery ? Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Are you actually working in within a wordpress (or even php) site / project?  The only way you would be getting `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` returned at the value of that variable is if you are not working in a wordpress (or even php) file.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side, so once everything executes on the server and the page loads, you can't change the PHP with client-side code.
The code provided by Nathan is right, but the quotes aren't quite right. You'd want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var templateDirectory = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>";
</script>
```

Check to see if that function returns a value or actually echoes it out. If it returns the value, you'll want it echoed instead (since you want the actual output of the bloginfo() function echoed into the javascript variable). The easiest way to do that without changing the function itself is to just echo it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var templateDirectory = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>";
</script>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of
get_theme_root_uri()& get_template

```
$qrImgLink = get_theme_root_uri()."/".get_template()."/qr/".$RandomToken.".png";
```